# EntityAspect.Delete() doesn't delete entity from navigation set after import - Breeze.Sharp

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

We are developing a mobile cross-platform app that uses Breeze.Sharp import and export operations for persisting data when device is in a zone with no network coverage.

When an entity is supposed to be deleted from the UI, we set **entity.EntityAspect.Delete()** and everything is fine: EntityState is set to Deleted and entity is removed from the navigation set (and the UI list). Then, we export the entities to a file via: **EntityManager.ExportEntities()**. When the app is closed and started again, we use **EntityManager.ImportEntities()** to import the entities from the file. That's where the issue happens. *The deleted entity is still a part of the navigation set it was deleted from* (it's in the navigation set and can be seen in the UI list even if it's EntityState is Deleted after import), and can be iterated through and manipulated as well as other non-deleted entities of the navigation set.

I've tried to reset the deleted entities' states to Deleted after import (with no luck):

```
this.EntityManager.ImportEntities(content, new ImportOptions(MergeStrategy.Disallowed, true));
foreach (var entity in this.EntityManager.GetEntities(EntityState.Deleted))
      {
          entity.EntityAspect.Delete(); // no luck
      }
```

There is the same issue filed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274992/breeze-deleted-items-nav-properties-bug), but it applies to breeze.js and doesn't seem to be fixed in the latest Breeze.Sharp. The solution provided there seems to work when there are multiple Entity Managers, but this is not our case, we have only one. We are using Breeze.Sharp version 0.6.0.5. (latest for now)

Can you confirm or provide a solution for this issue or provide an info if the fix is going to be in the next release?

Thanks